# API | Coinimp | user/withdraw | Invalid parameters (POST)

Tags: api, web-mining

Anyone here using coinimp and have the same problem with me?
Have you fixed it? can you help me?

So I am trying to test the POST of the user/withdraw, I followed the documentation of it at https://www.coinimp.com/documentation/http-api#user-withdraw which is clearly stated the parameters is site-key, user and amount. I already told them(to the support) that the API is not working..

[image]

My account currently have a total of **1 330 827**
[image]

I tried to POST via https://reqbin.com and https://web.postman.co and giving me the same error which is the:

```json
{
    "message": "Invalid parameters.",
    "status": "failure"
}
```

My API request is (POST + API KEY AND ID HEADER):

```
https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/user/withdraw?site-key={sitekey}&user={user_id}&amount={hash amount}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work if it is not form-data, I also used request library instead of axios.

Code:

```js
const mintmeWithdraw = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/user/withdraw",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "X-API-ID": 'api-id-here',
        "X-API-KEY": 'api-key-here'
    },
    formData : {
        "site-key" : `you-site-key`,
        "user" : `user-here`,
        "amount" : `hash-amount`
    }
};

request(mintmeWithdraw, async function (err, res, body) {
    if(err) throw err;
});
```